# creating UIButton programmatically is blurry than using storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uibutton

I have two custom UIButton with the same image.One is created programmatically which is blurry,the other is using storyboard which works fine.Here is the my code

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIButton *purchaseButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    purchaseButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    purchaseButton.frame=CGRectMake(0, 35.5+30, 177, 55);
    [purchaseButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GouMai1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.view addSubview:purchaseButton];
}
```

Here is the project download [link](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1pJFHlwB)(Because of GFW,I can only upload it to a Chinese website). Is that a Xcode bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    purchaseButton.frame=CGRectMake(0, 35.5+30, 177, 55);
```

There's your problem. Never give an interface object non-integral coordinates. It will be blurry! - You'll notice that in Interface Builder (storyboard) you *can't* do that.

The reason is that on the screen there are physical pixels, and there is no such thing as half a pixel: every pixel is either on or off, as it were. So if you use half-point coordinates, they cannot match pixels exactly, and the system will blur things to match (antialiasing etc.).

So, get rid of the `.5` and things will be much, much better.

Comment: Thank you.But in retina display,1 point=2 pixel,then 0.5 point=1 pixel.How can I locate 1 pixel without non-integral coordinates?

Comment: Do not think about pixels. Think about points. Your values in `frame` are points. Use integer values only.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what @matt is saying, you can do .5 now so long as it's a retina device. You can even have .5 widths and heights, that's how iOS 7 gets their very thin lines in some places.

When I run your sample app, in the Retina iPad simulator it is not blurry (well no more blurry than the source image). But in the non-Retina iPad simulator it is blurry, and this is because of the .5 in the frame.

You need to test the scale of the screen `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale` and add the .5 only if the scale is > 1.

Also note, you are creating two buttons with that code. You can remove the duplicate line `purchaseButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`

Answer (score 0):

```
purchaseButton.frame=CGRectMake(0, 35.5+30, 177, 55);
```

Actually

- Screen will have pixels and there wont be half pixel
- The coordinates we specify for UI Elements will be points.
- Point to pixel ratio will depend on dpi and ppi.

IOS primarily renders all things based on points and dpi and thus trying to use half point is causing blur. (Thats why we cant set the coordinates to points in interface builder)

So no floats are allowed forcing them causes blurness. please use nearest possible integer value.

On other hand since dividing even numbers with odd numbers will mostly give float point coefficients. we must use ceil and floor methods when performing calculations dynamically.

`purchaseButton.frame=CGRectMake(0, ceil(self.view.fram.size.width/3), 177, 55);`